# Django ListView Through Model Relationships

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have been reading through here and I can't seem to find the answer of the question I am looking for. Maybe I'm not asking the correct question.

I have three models.
Recruiter
Office
Recruit

Recruiters are assigned to multiple offices and each office has multiple employees. What I need to be able to do is create a listview that lists all of the employees that are associated with a recruiter. So something like this:

Recruiter 1 has Office 1 and 2 assigned to them. Office 1 has Employee 1,2,3. Office 2 has employee 3,4,5

The Listview should display all employees under Recruiter 1.

My Models are:

```
class Recruit(models.Model):
   id = models.CharField(max_length=25,primary_key=True, unique=True)
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   mobile_phone = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
   preferred_phone = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
   email= models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
   officeid = models.ForeignKey(Office,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,related_name="recruit")

class Office(models.Model):
   office_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   officeid = models.CharField(max_length=20,primary_key=True,unique=True)

class Recruiter(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='recruiter',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   organization = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Do I need a AssingedOffices table to join this all together?

```
class AssignedOffice(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   esa_office = models.ForeignKey(Office,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Just not sure how to connect them & display in the listview.

Edit Added start of view.

```
class MyESA(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
template_name = "recruits/recruits_list.html"
user= User.objects.select_related('recruiter')
paginate_by = 20
model=Recruit
context_object_name = 'recruits'

def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Recruit.objects.filter(probablity=1)
        return queryset
```

Comment: for which of the 3 models you are creating the ListView? Can you share the view code as well?

Comment: I would like to show a list of recruits that belong to the recruiters offices. updated to show the view I was working on.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to achieve a Many-to-one relationship like this

> Recruiters are assigned to multiple offices

then you should have a `ForeignKey` in the `Office` model not the other way around. I presume that each `Office` has one `Recruiter`. Otherwise you should have a Many-to-Many relationship that is constructed with a `ManyToManyField`

2. I presume that by

> each office has multiple employees

You meant that each `Office` object has multiple `Recruit` objects

3. If you want to list all of the `Recruit` objects in a ListView for model `Recruiter` then I think the easiest way would be to add a ForeignKey field in the `Recruit` model and refer to it via [related object reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/relations/)